# What is the best way to keep variables unchanged by the user?

Tags: security, variables, scope, closures

I have a large project I am working on, first thing that really contains sensitive data, and I am realizing that my variables are largely accessible to the global scope.

I am having some trouble privatizing them. My project is pure html5, and uses several script pages to keep things tidy.

#### Example A

```
let x = 0;
window.onload = function(){
console.log(x)
}
```

#### Example B

```
window.onload = function(){
let x = 0;

console.log(x)
}
```

These both works fine, However, the variable is accessible via console. Moving it into the function helps none, using var, nothing. I can't seem to make my variable read only, and yet available to the project. Would love some advice here.

Comment: Html5 with JS entirely runs on the client. The user has full control of the client, there is no way to "protect" your app from the user. This was discussed many times here.

Comment: Yes thank you, after a few attempts at research I found that information, obfuscation would be the best answer to provide. Thanks for your help regardless :)